# Something wrong with my ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, osx-yosemite

Always the same error:

```
AilixdeMacBook-Pro:~ Ailix$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
AilixdeMacBook-Pro:~ Ailix$ ruby -d
Exception `LoadError' at /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1240 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1249 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
Exception `NameError' at /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1257 - uninitialized constant Gem::Specification
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1257:in `': uninitialized constant Gem::Specification (NameError)
    from :1:in `require'
    from :1:in `'
AilixdeMacBook-Pro:~ Ailix$ gem -v
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1257:in `': uninitialized constant Gem::Specification (NameError)
    from :1:in `require'
    from :1:in `'
AilixdeMacBook-Pro:~ Ailix$ brew -v
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1257:in `': uninitialized constant Gem::Specification (NameError)
    from :1:in `require'
    from :1:in `'
AilixdeMacBook-Pro:~ Ailix$ pod repo
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1257:in `': uninitialized constant Gem::Specification (NameError)
    from :1:in `require'
    from :1:in `'
```

I guess something wrong with my ruby. But i don't know how to fix it

My environment:

```
MacOS 10.10.5
Xcode 7.2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is output from `ruby -e 'puts $:'` (if you're able ru run it)?

Comment: Actually looks bit strange having `rubygems` at `/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/`, my system one has it at `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0`. Try backing it up and removing

Comment: looks like your system ruby is broken, possibly due to an incompatible gem, although this won't fix the problem, have you tried a ruby manager like chruby? It's pretty quick to setup and means you can install/reinstall any ruby version

Comment: @maniacalrobot system ruby may be needed to set up its dependencies

Comment: @Vasfed true, and as you've pointed out, this is an odd location for Ruby.

Comment: @Ailix What does `which -a ruby` return?

Comment: @maniacalrobot `/usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: @Vasfed It works after I remove the whole folder `/Library/Ruby` Thank you guys

Comment: OS X depends on having its system Ruby in place and functional; blindly removing it seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @DaveNewton you mean the `Ruby` in `Library` is the OSX system Ruby?

Comment: @Ailix It's where the system Ruby keeps its gems/etc., yes. Or at least some of them--the system Ruby has artifacts in several locations.

Comment: @DaveNewton Right,I restore the `Ruby` and remove the `rubygems.rb` and `rubygems` folder in `/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0`

Comment: Never, ever, EVER `sudo gem` anything. You will break your system Ruby eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system ruby installation seems to be messed up. Try removing the offending `/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb` (and may be more of enclosing folders)

Ruby have its bundled rubygems at `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0` so it should work with these.

Once ruby is alive - you can try upgrading rubygems again by `sudo gem update --system` if needed, but I advise setting up a ruby version manager like `rvm` (rvm.io) and leave the system ruby be there only for emergences and backing the `brew`.

Comment: I wish this really solved the problem, instead of just putting wallpaper over it. The original problem is not solved, but rather, worked around with this answer.