# LoadError when installing homebrew

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, homebrew

I have tried below

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

to install homebrew on my mac. But it shows:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:1395:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `require'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
```

How can I fix it?

I have tried:

```
brew doctor
```

Then shows:

```
/usr/local/Library/brew.sh: line 177: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/brew.sh: line 177: exec: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

> Environment:
>
> Mac Mojave 10.14.2
>
> ruby 2.3.7p456

Comment: You probably have [something wrong with your system Ruby installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35240886/3784008). I recommend that you install Ruby through RVM: install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.6.0`; then retry installing brew.

Comment: I tried installing ruby with rvm and it failed with `Failed to update Homebrew`. I guess it needs homebrew to install ruby by rvm. How could I reinstall ruby without homebrew?

Comment: Try `rvm install 2.6.0 --autolibs=1`. More [here](https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs).